# ERC-721 safeTransferFrom() not working when sending an NFT from a regular address to a smart contract address

Tags: solidity, truffle, nft, openzeppelin

I'm testing transferring a minted NFT from a regular address to this smart contract's address (I'm creating a DEX), but whenever I test it with Truffle I get the error `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`.

```
contract Exchange is ERC721Enumerable {
    function sellToExchange(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _sellPrice) public {
       safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, payable(this), _tokenId);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I keep getting this error. If I call the exact same function with `transferFrom()` instead, it passes my test, but not with `safeTransferFrom()`.

I'm using OpenZeppelin's ERC721 contract by the way.

Also, should I make the smart contract's address a type of `address` or `address payable` in order to receive the NFT?

### ANSWER:

The issue was that in order to receive NFT/ERC721 tokens to a smart contract address, that address needs to inherit `ERC721Holder.sol` which is found on OpenZeppelin's contract GitHub repo (link below).

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/utils/ERC721Holder.sol

Comment: Has `msg.sender` authorized the contract to access to _tokenId? See approve in their docs https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-approve-address-uint256-

Comment: I figured out why. I needed to inherit `ERC721Receiver` to be able to let my contract accept NFT tokens.

Comment: It will be awesome if you could add the solution as an answer so it can help others.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `safeTransferFrom(ownerOf(_tokenId), payable(this), _tokenId);`

Comment: payable address is only for receiving ether, not tokens.